# CodeIgniter incomplete class name

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I got two controller in CodeIgniter, at the top of each one I load my library:

```
require_once(APPPATH.'/libraries/Client.php');
```

After that I load in the controller the session library with:

```
$this->load->library(array('session'));
```

Now when I create an `object` from the library in the first controller and place it in a session I'm not able to access it in the other controller. I get the following error:

> __PHP_Incomplete_Class

Anyone know a solution for this one?

Comment: Can you put your code ?

Comment: It says that before using it , you should define it somewhere else, then and then only you can use it. TRY to load your libraries and helpers in autoload.php will be fesible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your loading session library in controller in a wrong way. 
Load the library in config/autoload.php file like below-

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```

try this.